# Rails Thumbnails for videos being uploaded to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I have a rails application where I need to upload videos to an amazon s3 bucket alongwith their thumbnails. I am using ffmpeg to generate thumbnails and I am using carrierwave to handle video uploads. Here is my video uploader class

```
 class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Video
  storage :fog
  def store_dir
     "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  def extension_white_list
    %w(mp4 flv)
  end
end
```

The video uploads fine and the column for video url is set in videos table but I want to generate thumbnail and upload it as well. I know I have to use ffmpeg here but don't exactly know how to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using carrierwave to upload video to Amazon. You can use [carrierwave-video-thumbnailer](https://github.com/evrone/carrierwave-video-thumbnailer) To create thumbnail for video.

Just add `include CarrierWave::Video::Thumbnailer` in your uploader and related changes in uploader and you are done.